# Assign selinux context to the application without changing context of binary

Tags: security, selinux

Is there a way to assign custom SELinux context to the application despite the context that is assigned to it's binary?

Comment: Please explain the purpose of such a thing, maybe there is a better way to do what you want/need.

Comment: I am running the same application for different purposes with different options and arguments from the shell. I want to isolate them and write different policies.

Comment: You want to isolate different instances of the same app? from what? the rest of the system? isolate them from each other as well?

Comment: Yes, from each other and from the system, allow access only to the resources with specific contexts.

Comment: Application code cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app needs to support MCS ranges, because the binary is the same for all the instances. This is how it is done for VM isolation with [libvirt at RHEL systems](https://www.berrange.com/tags/mcs/), for example.

You can experiment by starting the different instances in different ranges using `runcon(1)`'s `-l` switch.

This way, you can use the same type enforcement for all the instances, while running every instance in a different category. That would isolate the instances from the rest of the system and between them at the same time.

Comment: heh, great, didn't knew about that and somehow google didn't find it too :D